# How to get owner function of another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cg33ov4g/3/

```
(function($){
    var foo='foo_value';
    var bar='bar_value';

    function getVar(theVar){
      console.log(this[foo]);
      console.log(this[bar]);
      //the code...
    }       

    $('.container').on('click', 'button', function(){
        getVar(this.dataset.target);
    })
}(jQuery))
```

What i want to achieve, is get the `foo_value` or `bar_value` after clicking the corresponding `button`.

I know, that i can do it just by checking `if(theVar==foo)`, but i am trying to find a way to get the scope of IIFE function (which wrapps the rest of code) and fetch variables foo and bar from it.
When i do `console.log(this)` (i thought it will point the owning function), but i get `window` object. I also tried to get to this variable dom window scope, but nothing worked properly.
Is there and option for doing this?

Comment: they would be just foo and bar - no this[] ... I may have misunderstood the question

Comment: by the way - in your code `this[foo]` would return the value of a property called `this.foo_value` - was that your intent?

Comment: accualy i want to get the variable, that is named as the theVar parameter of function getVat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jonva/7hfLsv5o/)

```
function getVar(theVar){
  console.log(this[foo]);
  console.log(this[bar]);
  //the code...
}
```

can be replaced with

```
function getVar(theVar){
 console.log(foo);
 console.log(bar);
 //the code...
}
```

`this[foo]` would return `undefined`:

1. `this` here is the context of the inner function i.e. `getVar`
2. Even if `this` were the outer context, the outer function does not have an object key by the name of `foo`. Instead, it has variables. If in fact you want to use this approach, try this:

   (function($){
       this.foo = 'foo_value';
       this.bar = 'bar_value';
       var self = this;
       function getVar(theVar){
         console.log(self[foo]);
         console.log(self[bar]);
         //the code...
       }

   ```
   this.foo_value = "some random string";
   this.bar_value = "some other string";

   $('.container').on('click', 'button', function(){
       getVar(this.dataset.target);
   })}(jQuery))
   ```

See a working example here

```js
 (function($){
        this.foo = 'foo_value';
        this.bar = 'bar_value';
        var self = this;
        function getVar(theVar){
          console.log(self[foo]);
          console.log(self[bar]);
          //the code...
        }       

        this.foo_value = "some random string";
        this.bar_value = "some random string";
   
        $('.container').on('click', 'button', function(){
            getVar(this.dataset.target);
        })
    }(jQuery))
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <button data-target='foo'>foo</button>
 <button data-target='bar'>bar</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> i want to get the variable, that is named as the theVar parameter of function getVar

In this case it would be easier to declare the variables as properties of an object. You can then use bracket notation to access those properties via a variable. Try this:

```js
var vars = {
  foo: 'foo_value',
  bar: 'bar_value'
}

function getVar(theVar) {
  console.log(vars[theVar]);
}

getVar('foo');
getVar('bar');
```